# Cannot access view located in area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[Edited:  code shown here updated based on recommendations based by NightOwl88 and Jasen in the replies]   This is embarrassing as I've solved the problem for others on several occasions.  Perhaps I've stared at it too long; I just can't find the answer to one of the most frequently asked questions on Stack Overflow.

I've got a view located in an MVC area and I cannot access it.  When I click on a link, I get the infamous error:

==========================================

The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /EIS/Translation/Translation/

## Index

I've done all the obvious: checking spelling; locations of controllers, views, etc.  I'll eat crow now and confess my stupidity.  Can someone please spot where I'm going wrong?

Partial snip of my controller code, TranslationController.cs:

```
namespace EIS.Web.Areas.Translation.Controllers
{
    public class TranslationController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

My view, Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Translation Dashboard";
}

<h2>Translation Dashboard</h2>
```

My area registration:

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
                       "Translation_default",
                       "Translation/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                       new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                       new[] { "EIS.Web.Areas.Translation.Controllers" }
                   );
    }
```

My project organization:

[image]

The markup that generates the link that doesn't work (/EIS/Translation/Index):

```
  <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Translation", new { area = "Translation" } )" class="homeLink" onmouseover="$('#mnTranslationLink').attr('src', '@Url.Content("~/")Images/translationwhite.png');" onmouseout="$('#mnTranslationLink').attr('src', '@Url.Content("~/")Images/translationblack.png');" alt="Translation" title="Translation">
                        <img id="mnGovernanceLink" style="margin-top: 8px; border: none !important;" src="@Url.Content("~/")Images/translationblack.png" width="25" height="21" alt="Translation" title="Translation" />
                    </a>
```

I've stared at this for hours now and just can't see it.  I know it's obvious and I'm going to feel like an idiot when I see the answer.  But I'll be a grateful idiot when I see it.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why aren't you using `@Url.Action("action", "controller", routeValues: new { area = "area" })` instead of concatenating the Content path for `href`?

Comment: Thanks Jasen.  I inherited this code and all of the other (working) links it generates use the  concatenation pattern, even though I agree it looks ugly and prone to break.  I tried your suggestion with an action of "Index", a controller of "TranslationController", and an area of "Translation", and am met with the same 404 error, this time the reported missing URL is "/EIS/Translation/TranslationController"

Comment: "EIS" is your application name? "Translation" is your area name? Controller name is also "Translation"? Then `@Url.Action("Index", "Translation", new { area = "Translation" })`.

Comment: Appreciate the help Jasen.  You are correct on all of the naming.  I tried your suggestion.  That results in a 404 error with the missing URL reported as "/EIS/Translation/Translation"   Doesn't even trigger a hit on a breakpoint in the controller.  The closest I've come so far is akerra's markup below, which does hit a breakpoint in the Index action in the TRanslation controller, but then an exception is thrown looking for the Index.cshtml view even though it is absolutely, with 100% certainty, present (as shown in the screen snapshot of my project in the OP)

Comment: Your namespace may be missing ".Controllers".

Comment: It was indeed missing .Controllers and I thought that was going to be the solution.  Good call.  That should have solved it, but did not.  The error I am getting back is reporting that there is no index.cshtml in the very location where there is, with 100% certainty, an index.cshtml.  Many thanks for the great suggestions though.

Comment: Jasen, please see the answer  I posted.  I think you gave me the solution in your comment and it took a clearing of the temporary asp.net files to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Url.Action() to create the link. Then use the routeValues and htmlAttributes parameters to provide styling / your mouseover event / etc.
This will generate the fully qualified URL.

This is what it should look like:

```
<a href"@Url.Action("Index", "Translation")" class="homeLink" onmouseover="$('#mnTranslationLink').attr('src', '@Url.Content("~/")Images/translationwhite.png');" onmouseout="$('#mnTranslationLink').attr('src', '@Url.Content("~/")Images/translationblack.png');" alt="Translation" title="Translation">
    <img id="mnGovernanceLink" style="margin-top: 8px; border: none !important;" src="@Url.Content("~/")Images/translationblack.png" width="25" height="21" alt="Translation" title="Translation" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt.  That doesn't work unfortunately.  It generates a bad url of the form:  http://localhost/EIS/Home/~/Translation/Index

Comment: Thanks much akerra.  This is a step forward.  I'm now finally hitting a breakpoint in the controller now, but am getting the infamous "the view Index or its master" was not found,the following locations were searched...  However, there is with 100% certainty a view named Index.cshtml underneath the /Views/Translation path, so I'm completely baffled.   On a whim, thinking maybe MVC wasn't looking in the AREA's view folder, I tried adding a routevalue to the Url.Action() in your example, like so: routeValues: new { area = "Translation" }, but this returns a 404 error.

Comment: A clue... The area seems to be getting lost in the mapping, even though I've tried explicitly putting it into the Url.Action().  If I go into the controller and hardcode the path to the view in the return() statement, as follows, then the view is found.  Else, the way MVC does its default search for a matching view fails.  I can't get it to find the view in the area, even if I specify the area in the url.action.  Here's the ugly code I have in my controller:     return View("~/Areas/Translation/Views/Translation/Index.cshtml");

Comment: Just `return View("Index")`.

Comment: Thanks Jasen, but that doesn't work.  Without specifying the full path including the area, I get the all-too-familiar message indicating all of the paths that have been searched looking for the view, but that it couldn't be found.

Answer (score 0):

Your requested URL is

```
/EIS/Translation/Index
```

The area route definition is:

```
context.MapRoute(
               "Translation_default",
               "Translation/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
               new[] { "EIS.Web.Areas.Translation.Controllers" }
           );
```

Clearly, these do not match. To match this route, the URL would have to be

```
/Translation/Translation/Index
```

Routing is based on a simple concept - the first match wins. If `@Url.Action("Index", "Translation", new { area = "Translation" })` does't generate the correct URL, then it is matching a route with the same set of route values that is registered *before* the route you have posted. This includes the order that `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` is called in relation to `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)` and `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` is called in relation to `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()`.

You have to analyze the entire routing configuration to work out why the route you are expecting to match is not the route you are matching.

Comment: Thanks NightOwl.  When I click the link, I'm actually getting a search on the path http://localhost/EIS/Translation/Translation and a reported failure to find Index.cshtml, with the usual runthrough of the near-dozen default locations it looks for.  I do indeed have the right file in the correct location.  Jasen caught one thing I thought was the solution: ".Controllers" was missing from the area name in my controller.  Alas, that didn't solve it either.  In the interest of lost time I think I'm going to be forced to drop the Areas approach.  Frustrating :-(

Comment: @markaaronky - I have updated my answer. Please post your *entire* routing configuration, including the order the methods I mentioned are called in. That is the only way to get to the bottom of why your link is being generated wrong.

Comment: I've updated my posted code as requested. 
 As for the routing answers, AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() is the first call made in Application Start; RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes) is called 3 lines later.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found the answer thanks to a tip from Jasen... the ".Controllers" was missing from the namespace of my controller.  Even after I added it to the namespace and cleaned and rebuilt the project, it still failed and runtime.

I checked all off the route verification ordering thanks to Owl88's excellent commments--still no luck.

Then, on a whim, I went and cleared all the cached temporary ASP.NET files under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

Believe it or not, on the next run, routing worked perfectly.  I had made no other changes.